# Why do we need device drivers, why can't we just send/receive data over Serial?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, kernel-module

I'm going to use the `Arduino board` as an exmaple. We can talk to this device (I'm assuming without any drivers?) using UART Serial transmission.
Using the USB to Serial chip on the board.

I know drivers are usually running in Kernel mode, in Linux `Kernel Modules` are used to add
new drivers and `system calls` to enable talking with different peripherals.

But can't we use the same analogy of an Arduino? Just use the `read/write` system call of Linux to send and receive bits with the device?

Of course I'm only taking about USB/Serial devices and not things like Graphic cards.

Comment: the read/write system calls talk to the drivers -- the driver is what translates/moves the data between the read/write call buffers and the hardware device registers

Comment: why can't read/write directly use the a buffer? I guess the driver handles how to route the bits or maybe wraps them?

Comment: Because every device can be different. There is no magic fairy dust that can automatically convert the same control/data into something that every single device can understand. Initialisation, timing, data framing, error detection, error correction, etc are a few examples of things that a device driver may need to handle.

Comment: I assume its all standard Serial communication, SPI or UART? pre-defined protocols? then there could be a software on the device which puts the received data in correct registers of the device and does error handling?

Answer (score 0):

> We can talk to this device (I'm assuming without any drivers?

no, there is a driver for the bootlaoder ch340 in most cases
it's pre-installed in your system

Comment: so then why would a let's say a printer or webcam need another driver? they are not communicating over the same ch340 (usb to serial) driver?

Comment: the CH340 is a chip on the arduino , and yes for each device need a drive to communicate with the computer

Comment: Arduino doesn't have a ch340 btw, it uses another air 16u2 chip instead.

Comment: there is many versions with diffrent bootlaoder , ch340 is one of them(in most case for clone versions) , and yes there is also 16u2

Comment: in any case, I'm assuming my pc also has a serial to usb converter, aren't these two chips able to communicate in UART without any drivers?

Comment: in fact the serial to usb convert has achip FTDI or ch340, and this chip need a driver

Comment: but,look the driver already exist you dont have to design  a driver,  and in this case why you face a problem with the driver since it's exist and pre installed in your computer?!!